# Determine route between rooms

Tags: path-finding

Is there a general purpose algorithm to determine a route between rooms of a building?

Imagine a fixed-layout, single-level house with 50+ rooms. Assume I have a data structure that defines the exits of each room and the room to which each exit leads. I'd like to know how to get from room 4 in the NW corner to room 37 in the E side, say. I want the shortest list of rooms that need to be traversed. (I don't need to see this graphically in real-time.)

Is it worth finding such an algorithm or should I just 'map out' the level and use the pathfinding abilities of my game dev platform of choice..

edit: removed the A* reference

Comment: Your question became offtopic this way. We don't support questions asking fro technology recommendations

Comment: I'm not really asking for a recommendation on which tech to use, just mentioning what I'm using in case it limits the solution, but point taken.

Comment: May I ask why you removed the [tag:game-maker] tag?

Comment: @Bálint A* is an algorithm, not a technology.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica I used the word "technology" because I didn't want to write the whole `Questions about "how to get started," "what to learn next," or "which technology to use" are discussion-oriented questions which involve answers that are either based on opinion, or which are all equally valid. Those kinds of questions are outside the scope of this site. Visit our help center for more information.` thing. The question asks for something, that can be answered in many different way correctly

Comment: Yeah I removed the GMS tag after @Bálint comment about recommending tech. I thought I'd use the tag, seeing as it's there.

Comment: @codah If you feel that the technology you're using (e.g. GMS) would make it harder to create an algorithm such as A* for XYZ reason, adding the tag is appropriate, it says "I want to do that specifically in GMS". I believe that the technology recommendation that he was talking about is "is there an algorithm that does X". If you've tried what the other question/answer suggests, and a bunch of what other answers on this site suggests and it still does not work, I suggest editing your question, stating just that, and ask for reopening the question.

Comment: The idea is that if it's not easy to do A* in GMS, it could be a good candidate for a canonical question about that.

Answer (score 12):

You have a common misconception. A* isn't made for grids, it usually uses graphs. A grid is just a specialized graph with each node having 4 edges (apart from the edges and corners).

Comment: Thanks, you're right I didn't think before writing that. My question still stands though-is it worth finding a 'simpler' algorithm due to my simple needs and fixed map, or go with standard pathfinding techniques? I'm new to GameMaker but can't see support for graphs.

Comment: @codah A* is very simple, the only way you can go simpler is probably Dijkstra, but that isn't optimized for game development.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm getting the vibe that this *is* just a general pathfinding problem, suitable for A* etc, but maybe not easily implementable in GML(?)

Comment: @codah Nothing should stop you from implementing it and it shouldn't be that hard

Comment: Although dijkstra isnt optimized it might be faster to implement without noticing any difference when its only a 50-ish node graph. You could always optimize later.

Comment: A* is very easy to implement on general graphs. It's like 50 lines of code. Should be very simple in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any particular general purpose solution for this, although most certainly there are people who have solved this multiple times, in various ways.

One could well use the available/built-in pathfinding abilities, this should work fine but is probably not the primary issue.

The challenge is to define an optimal node graph. This depends on how greedily the task should be solved, and also on the particular features of the environment. Apparently, a building has for example corridors, and apparently it is sometimes fastest to pass a corridor diagonally, ie. enter it by it's left wall and leaving it by it's right wall? Maybe there are rooms that need to be crossed diagonally or along some of it's walls? Staircases?

I would probably (as i like to control things myself) solve this by first creating a node graph that holds all possible nodes (points), ie. every corner and every door (even left and right edge of it separately?) is a node, or holds a node very nearby. Then I'd perform a "all nodes against all nodes" test and create a link between two nodes whenever they can see each other directly (could even use the 3D engines hit testing for that, if there is a building model available); at the same time calculate the distances as graph weights. This would create the "full set" node graph. Finally, I'd execute "go from each room to each other room" pathfinding tasks and mark any node/link that was ever used with 1. To naturally then remove from the graph all such nodes/links that were never used. This would create the minimum node graph that covers for all possible movement, suitable for runtime use, to be embedded with the application. And also be a test for the overall functionality - perhaps an extra node bust be inserted somewhere because of some unexpected reason?

Comment: I think I'll to accept this as the answer. I was simply trying to avoid having to 'map out' all the walls in my level as physics objects, then learn the ins and outs of whatever platform's pathfinding and all its quirks (I've done that once in Construct2 and didn't want to repeat the pain in GMS). My map is very simple and will never change. No stairs/levels; corridors are treated as rooms. Writing a 'proper' PF algorithm for this seemed overkill. I'd even be happy with a 'hacky' solution that just works. As a couple of other commenters have said, maybe just implement the A* :)

Comment: I did somethng similar, a bit larger, in one project. Entered ca 7000 nodes by clicking the mouse (had some automation and visual guidance, wrote a small app). Was quite fun, actually, as my choices reflected people's real life behaviour - i had to say how people would act in various situations:-). Anyway, i then just pass that data to a standard pathfinding algo, and voilá. A* etc solvers should be standard copypaste meat, defining the good nodes&links may require a bit more effort but one can always even type coords and links in Notepad and have the proggy parse.